# jQuery effect not working in Wordpress template file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have my template file for home page, Home-template.php, and in it I have a sliding menu html.

This is my script for sliding menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("fast");


}); 

// Collapse Panel
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideUp("fast"); 
});     

$(".toggle a").click(function () {
    $(".toggle a").toggle();
});     
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

and both jquery and this script are loaded on the page but the slide effect doesnt work, its only poping up and down without effect.

Any help?

here is html code:

```
<div id="panel">    
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About me</a></li>        
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="toggle"><a id="close" style="display: none;position:   absolute;right:5px;top:5px;" class="close" href="#"></a></div>   
<div class="toggle" style="position: absolute;right:10px;top:10px;"><a id="open"    class="open" href="#"></a></div>
```

here is a link of a page:
http://pavlovic.com/about-me/

Comment: what is that `e.preventDefault();` for?

Comment: As it is e is not defined so you would get the reference error:
ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: its the same whitout it, effects dont work, not showing errors

Comment: Maybe you have too many jquery files being loaded and somehow causing a conflict. Check the source. Some themes/plugins load their own version of jquery.

Comment: checked that too, not a problem there.. I think it is a problem because I have code in .php file, not in page editor, and than effect doesnt work, but I dont know how to solve this

Comment: Well from the code you've shown, except for the undefined `e`, there doesn't seem to be any errors. Show us your HTML code.

Comment: I updated with html code

Comment: @WebNovice here is a link of the page in the post, so you can see it

Comment: I see two jquery being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Well for one the e is not defined and secondly I'm not sure how you are including your js so
you should read this: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Comment: I included my js in the header and in my source the js is loaded, but the effect wont work, it just goes up and down without effects

Answer (score 0):

try the following code which works for me

```
$(this).effect('slide', { direction: 'down'}, 500);
```

for the slide effect to work in wordpress along with jquery file the jquery-effects-core and jquery-effects-slide has to be also loaded.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-slide');
```

this code also works:

```
$('#test').effect( "slide", "right" );
```